# Legendre symbol question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an integer $N \geq 2$, are there infinitely many integers $d$ such that the Legendre symbol $(\frac{d}{p}) = 1$ for all prime $p \leq N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the primes $\le N$ be $p_0$ to $p_k$.
Consider the system of congruences 
$d\equiv 1^2\pmod{p_i}$, $i=0$ to $k$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, this system has infinitely many solutions. Each is a quadratic residue modulo all the $p_i$.

Comment: Even stronger, there are infinitely many such primes $d$....

Answer (score 0):

Why restrict to $p\le N$?  Just take $d=k^2$ and you have $(\frac{d}{p}) = 1$ for all primes $p$ (except for those dividing $k$).